# How to Extend Google Now Voice Commands in Android with Custom Actions

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-now

I recently installed the Google Now Launcher on my Nexus 4, and it got me thinking about how I could use it to interact with my own apps. While I can open my app by asking for it by title, I was wondering if there's a way to intercept the voice commands (possibly through a broadcast receiver) so I can say something like "turn off living room light" to send a signal to an Arduino to turn off the light in a room across the house? On the same note, I haven't been able to find the documentation for Google Now, so if that's out there I would love to see the link for it so I can just read what's available from the source.

Comment: Would also very much like to know. Did you ever find out Paul?

Comment: Not possible yet, as they haven't opened up the API for it.

Comment: Thats a shame, how have apps like Evernote and Timely done it then?

Comment: Guys in your category for the activity you need to have the Category set as the default clock application with the ability to handle events. Both need to be registered in the Manifest. I know it's late. But I hope it helps

Comment: It must be possible as auto voice does it (via accessibility I think)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do it using the Android-Intent model.
Google Now fires various intents after parsing your command, and if the phone has an app registered to handle such intent, google now will who user the options to execute the command. 
Common Intents are: Alarm, Fitness, Media
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Now

Comment: Worth to note that today (Nov 2015) generic actions are not yet supported in public as described in https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions